# How can I strip down JavaScript code while building HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security

I am trying to parse some HTML to find images within it.

For example, I created a dynamic `div` and parsed the tags like this:

```
var tmpDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
tmpDiv.innerHTML = html;
```

The HTML should be script-less however there are exceptions, one code segment had the following code under an image tag:

```
<img src=\"path" onload=\"NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);\" />
```

By creating a temp `div` the "onload" function invoked itself and it created a JavaScript error.

Is there anyway to tell the browser to ignore JavaScript code while building the HTML element?

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that later on I'd like to display this HTML inside a `div` in my document so I'm looking for a way to ignore script and not use string manipulations.

Thanks!

Comment: if the onload is still the same, you can use `tmpDiv.innerHtml = html.replace('onload="NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);',"")`

Comment: That will solve this specific case but I'm looking for a generic solution that will cover every other case.

Comment: Every other case of what?  All onload handlers?  All what?

Comment: All other cases of scripts that are implicitly called from the HTML(not the script that's inside the java script tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is to loop through the children of the div and remove the event handlers you wish.

Consider the following:

We have a variable containing some HTML which in turn has an `onload` event handler attached inline:

```
var html = "<img src=\"http://www.puppiesden.com/pics/1/doberman-puppy5.jpg\" 
alt=\"\" onload=\"alert('hello')\" />"
```

One we create a container to put this HTML into, we can loop through the children and remove the relevant event handlers:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
$(newDiv).html(html);
$(newDiv).children().each(function(){this.onload = null});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XWrP3/

**UPDATE**

The OP is asking about removing other events at the same time. As far as I know there's no way to remove all events in an automatic way however you can simply set each one to `null` as required:

```
$(newDiv).children().each(function(){
    this.onload = null;
    this.onchange = null;
    this.onclick = null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, as I wrote in my latest comment to ilia, I'm looking for a way to remove all the events because my final goal is to show this HTML and scripts could trigger in various events.

Comment: You can remove as many events are you like this way. There's no universal way to remove all events. You'll need to just set each event that you're concerned about to null.

Comment: oh, too bad, Well I'll have to write them all manually i guess. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it really easily with jquery like this:

EDIT:

html

```
<div id="content" style="display:none">
    <!-- dynamic -->
</div>
```

js

```
$("#content").append(
    $(html_string).find('img').each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("onload");
        console.log($(this).attr("src"));
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me it does the same as creating a div and i forgot to mention that i'd like to display this HTML later so I'm looking for a different solution. (And u got up-vote from me)

Comment: Updated. im pretty sure jquery strips `<script>` tags when parsed

Comment: Probably, but here's the problem, in my code there aren't any script tags at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy and this will probably do the trick, However when I'll show the HTML there will be probably tons of other events that could trigger scripts is there a way to remove all the events from an object?

Comment: `$(html_string).children().die().unbind().removeAttr("onclick").removeAttr("onload")` etc...